# How to parse string field with unlimited characters postgresql

Tags: string, postgresql, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string field in PostgreSQL to use as a filter. 
The field looks like this:

```
This Cup R4.5.2.234 | Ver: 20160303
```

I am trying to get out the "5.2.234". The problem with using left() is that not every value has the same number of characters before getting to the values I want.

```
This Glass R4.3.1 | Ver: 20160221
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `substring()` function.  It would be something like this:

```
select substring(col from 'R4.([0-9.]+) ')
```

Comment: Thanks! What about ones that don't have an R in front of them at all? So it is just "This Glass 3.1.23".

Comment: You should learn about regex, which is what substring() is using. To answer your question, the pattern you want for that would be something like '[0-9.]+'. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html